# nextjs primereact datatable : fails to render if mapped

Tags: reactjs, next.js, datatable, primereact

I want to render child array in “results” from api to datatable primereact but  with my code not shown the data to the table only render blank data with only index. I assume after remap the data format array was change to another format that cause the datatable primereact cannot the shown the data.

The sandbox example showcasing the error can be found in the following link:
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/bl4ckimpact/datatable_primereact_tanstackquery_mapping/main?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fdatatable%2Fpage.tsx&worksp=

i try to change "limit" on api link that cause change the datatable index